# How to change width of material-ui's drawer dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to change the width of the material-ui's *Drawer* component on window resize. 
In the documentation the width is applied like this `classes={{ paper: classes.root }}` but the problem is that you can't change the `classes.root` dynamically as it is a constant.

I've also tried to set the width with `classes={{ paper: {width: drawerWidth } }}`, but no luck.

example:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        width: "70%"
    }
}));
funciton Example(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    var dynamicWidth = "70%";

    function setDynamicWidth() ...

    return (
        <Drawer
            classes={{
                paper: { width: dynamicWidth }
            }}
        >
            ...
        </Drawer>
    );
}
```

Comment: Add a minimal sample of your code and we'll try to help you

Answer (score 0):

Use `useMediaQuery` to this:

```
  const matchDownMd = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('lg'));

    return (
        <Drawer
            width={matchDownMd ? '70%' : 'auto'}
        >
            ...
        </Drawer>
    );
```

Material-UI provides default values for 'xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl', but you can always customize them by yourself.